# How can I make the zero tick appear in the lefthand corner in R plots?

Tags: r, graph

When you generate plots in R with the 'plot' command, and set the left side x-axis limit to zero, with, e.g.

```
plot(x=c(1:10), y=c(1:10), xlim=c(0,10), ylim=c(0,10))
```

R, for reasons which are not apparent to me, puts a bunch of extra space between the point (0,0) and the bottom lefthand corner (also at the top).

I can get the graph I want by manually guessing the offsets, and adjusting the bottom and left axis limits accordingly:

```
plot(x=c(1:10), y=c(1:10), xlim=c(0.38,10), ylim=c(0.38,10))
```

But the problem is, I have to do this manually for each graph, which seems excessive.

Is there a par-type setting for removing this margin?

Comment: Just so you know, the reason (or at least, _a_ reason) is that a lot of people think that that looks nicer.

Comment: It does look nicer, but some venues have strange formatting requirements. :)

Comment: It isn't that it necessarily looks nicer. Look at @Josh O'Brien's plot below; what has happened to the point at (10,10)? That is just wrong. The 4% padding helps avoid those issues in general usage, but you have all the tools required to change these defaults as Josh shows.

Comment: @Gavin is of course right, and I answered your question in the narrowest of ways. Here's code for a nicer looking plot that still plots the zero ticks in the lower-left hand corner: `d<-1:10 ; r<-c(0, 1.04*max(d)); plot(d, xlim=r, ylim=r, xaxs="i", yaxs="i")`

Comment: @JoshO'Brien this was what I was doing in practice, just used a simpler example to illustrate things. The problem was that I needed the origin to appear at exactly (0,0), and putting it at (0,0) didn't do the trick!

Comment: Makes sense. That's the exact situation where I've needed `xaxs` and `yaxs` in the past.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien That wasn't intended as dig at your answer, just a comment on the earlier comments. Your answer is spot on.

Comment: @GavinSimpson I really like that SO has these ways for answers to be edited, annotated, and commented upon. Plus, it was me that said my answer was narrow. So no offense taken at all!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In calls to `plot()`, both `xlim` and `ylim` are by default padded (extended) by 4%. To suppress this behavior, set `xaxs = "i"` and/or `yaxs = "i"`.

For more details, see the [help page for `par`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/par.html).

```
plot(x=c(1:10), y=c(1:10), xlim=c(0,10), ylim=c(0,10), xaxs="i", yaxs="i")
```

[image]