# How determinant is ylim in R's plot()? What overrides it?

Tags: r, plot

Something appears to take precedence over the `ylim` parameter in a plot in R.

Coding

```
> plot(c(0,1), c(-30,30), ylim = c(-32,32))
> text(x = .5, y = -40:40, labels = -40:40, cex = .5)
```

returns a y limit bigger than the setting. Any idea why this is so in such simple graph? How can the `ylim` setting be given teeth?

[image]

**Edit**

As someone pointed out, a good answer exists here: [How can I make the zero tick appear in the lefthand corner in R plots?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9755479/how-can-i-make-the-zero-tick-appear-in-the-lefthand-corner-in-r-plots). When I searched for the problem, that title did not suggest a connection with my issue.

I would drop my redundant question, but someone has left an answer... What is the stackoverflow etiquette?

Comment: What do you mean by "given teeth"?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9755512/980833) or the documentation for `xaxs` in the help page for `?par`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

after you created a plot call

```
par('usr')
```

This will give you x and y limits; for your example

```
plot(c(0,1), c(-30,30), ylim = c(-32,32))
text(x = .5, y = -40:40, labels = -40:40, cex = .5)
par('usr')
[1]  -0.04   1.04 -34.56  34.56
```

your y limits with margins are -34.56 and 34.56. 
These are controlled by 'xaxs' and 'yaxs' parameters, check ?par

> Style ‘"r"’ (regular) first extends the data range by 4
>             percent at each end and then finds an axis with pretty labels
>             that fits within the extended range.
>             Style ‘"i"’ (internal) just finds an axis with pretty labels
>             that fits within the original data range.

If you set it them to 'i' it will give them exact ranges

```
par(xaxs = 'i', yaxs = 'i')
plot(c(0,1), c(-30,30), ylim = c(-32,32))
text(x = .5, y = -40:40, labels = -40:40, cex = .5)
```